# Localisation of Image

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

I  am asked to do the localization of an old project. I did all the text part.
But I am stuck on Images.

```
    <img id="img78" src="~/images/f1/step.jpg"  runat="server" alt="image2" width="267" />`
```

This is one of the image tag  I am struggling to fix. I have different images for German and French.

This is in a `UserControl`. I have 3 different resource file on the `LocalResources` folder of the `UserControl`. All text fields are working.

This is due in 2 days. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to programming. This project is done in old asp.net.

Is it possible to set the `src` from `LocalResourceFile`.

I tried the following way but didn't work:

```
    <img id="img78" src='~/images/<%= GetLocalResourceObject("step1") %>/step1_2.jpg'  runat="server" alt="image2" width="267" />
```

My ResourceFiles are `Activate.ascx`, `Activate.ascx.de`,  `Activate.ascx.fr`

```
ResoucefileEntry :-  (Name)step1.Text 
                     (value)g1
```

I need to change the url for `<img src=>`

```
for German as `src="~/images/g1/step.jpg"`
for French as `src="~/images/f1/step.jpg"`
for English as `src="~/images/e/step.jpg"`  This is the default.
```

Comment: "This is due in 2 days." - I'll give you an answer in 3 days.

Comment: You cannot interpolate render-blocks (`<%= %>` and `<%: %>`) with  elements using `runat="server"`. You'll need to set the `src=""` either using a `<%# %>` data-binding expression (hint: **don't**: ASP.NET WebForms' data-binding is a world of pain and results in horrible HTML that makes IE5.5 blush) - or by setting the `Src` property in your code-behind.

Comment: It would help if you could show us what's in the image - if it has text in it, why not just render the text in HTML and use a text-less image as a background behind it?

Comment: The images  have button with text in it. But  the image provided is already  in translated form. I don't want to change the image .Just wanted to load it when the user change the language.

Comment: How does your application code know what language to use?

Comment: Have you seen this article? https://juristr.com/blog/2011/01/aspnet-organize-your-resources-correct/

Comment: There is  a Link button that the user selects for each language. I changed the  images on the button click event.